# What term should we adopt for Speedlights/Speedlites?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

I think we need a tag for small, hotshoe mountable flashes. You could then tag your question with `[flash]` for questions that could also include other kinds of flash - I'm thinking things like Alien Bees etc. here - and additionally `[speedlight]` (or whatever) for a question related specifically to small strobes (if you were short of tags you could drop the `[flash]` tag???). As per normal you could add a `[canon]`/`[nikon]`/`[whoever]` tag if your question was brand specific.

I suggest either `[speedlight]` or `[speedlite]`, the latter being the Canon spelling. Personally, I'd go with the `[speedlight]`, despite being a Canon user, but I'm open to any suggestions to cover hotshoe-mountable flashes.

Answer (score 3):

How about `[flashgun]`?

The other option I could think possibly isn't as intuitive, but `[hotshoe-flash]` (and then the consistent `[studio-flash]` and `[(on)camera-flash]`) - this allows people to have `[*flash]` as an interesting/ignored tag, but I'm not sure people would discover them as easily...

Comment: I like the [*flash] approach. After all hotshoe-flash and studio-flash are potentially quite different topics.

Comment: I like the idea behind that, but `[hotshoe-flash]` and `[on-camera-flash]` seem clumsy and unnatural, and it's kind of forced so it fits the pattern. I certainly expect `[studio-flash]` to become a tag, though.

Comment: What about `[small-flash]`, then?

Answer (score 2):

I think that most brand-agnostic question about using small flashes apply similarly to studio units (they work the same way after all), so tagging them with `[flash]` seems ok to me.

Comment: For some things, such as light modifiers, there is a difference. There are plenty of softboxes, for example, that have mounts for hot-shoe flashes, and the vast majority of standard softboxes wouldn't fit a speedlight. Conversely, AFAIK, the Honl strap won't fit studio flashes.

Comment: True, that topic would benefit from a specific tag.

Answer (score 2):

I vote `[speedlight]`.  That seems to be the general term I see for hot shoe flashes on the Net, and I don't automatically think "Nikon" when I see it, even though I shoot Canon.

Comment: I'm also a Canon user, and I presumed we'd go for `[speedlight]` when I asked the question. I'll leave it open for a few more days, but it seems we're either going to settle for `[speedlight]` or `[small-flash]` (or similar).