# 'strobes' vs. 'flash'?

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

I've seen a couple of posts pop up with [`[strobes]`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strobes); I think we may want to prefer `[flash]` or, at least, the variations discussed here: [What term should we adopt for Speedlights/Speedlites?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/what-term-should-we-adopt-for-speedlights-speedlites)

Any objections/other opinions?

Comment: I agree, but that seems like not enough for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the distinction is somewhere around what [fresnel lens question suggests](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/why-do-hotshoe-flashes-use-fresnel-lens-but-studio-strobes-do-not): "strobe" almost always refers to studio equipment, so we might use them when having questions that deal with those.

So what about having:

- `[flash]` as generic term for something that delivers short burst of light
- `[strobes]` for studio units
- <del>`[small-flash]`</del> `[hotshoe-flash]` for hotshoe-mounted, battery powered stuff, which we'd call `[speedlights]` or `[speedlites]` in case we wanted to talk about specific brand

Comment: +1 - but personally I think I would suggest `[hotshoe-flash]` over `[small-flash]` or `[speedlight]`/`[speedlite]`. "Hotshoe" is brand neutral, and there are small units intended for studio use (such as small slave units and such), so "small" might not quite hit the target.

Comment: I guess preference for "small flash" comes from Strobist where it's more common, maybe different resources tend to call them "hotshoe":  http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=small+flash+site%3Astrobist.blogspot.com&word2=hotshoe+flash+site%3Astrobist.blogspot.com

Comment: As a non-strobist, "small-flash" is not as obviously referring to *all* flashguns as "hotshoe-flash", which is pretty immediately obvious to me.  E.g., Contax TLA200: small flash.  Canon 580: not small flash.  (Aside: is the distinction on strobist maybe down to the emphasis on off-camera use of these flashes?)

Comment: It could be because of that. Changed to hotshoe, then.